# Restricting access to pages but not to start page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC web application and I'm trying to restrict access to pages.

I've specified that I want to use forms authentication in my Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/login" timeout="20" protection="All" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    ...
</system.web>
```

This will deny access to all pages, but I want to make some pages public. I can do this in Web.config as well:

```
<location path="about-us">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="contact-us">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
…
```

This works all fine. The problem is the start page, more precisely when the user goes to "http://www.mydomain.com/", with no further path specified. How can I specify that this page should be public?

I've tried some variations, but nothings seems to work. I always get an error:

**No path**

```
<location>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

**Empty path**

```
<location path="">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

**Dot**

```
<location path=".">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

**Slash**

```
<location path="/">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manage authentication in your web.config for MVC. Trying using the `[Authorize]` attribute on your Controller classes and methods:

```
[Authorize] // everything here requires auth
public class AdminController()
{
    public ActionResult Dashboard() { ... }
}
```

---

```
public class ReportController()
{
    [Authorize] // only this method requires auth
    public ActionResult SecretReport() { ... }

    public View PublicReport() { ... }
}
```

---

```
// everything here is accessible
public class HomeController()
{
    public ActionResult Index() { ... }

    public ActionResult AboutUs() { ... }

    public ActionResult ContactUs() { ... }
}
```

In ASP.NET MVC you can use `[AllowAnonymous]` which allows you to do exactly that on a specific method

Comment: Thanks for the reply hunter, I will check out the Authorize attribute. Although I would prefer if I could do the same thing with attributes as I am trying to do with Web.config, i.e. require authorization for all controllers and actions as a default and then make exceptions for single controllers or actions. Most of my pages will be restricted and I really don't want to forget to restrict something...

Comment: In that case I would create a `BaseController` class with the `[Authorize]` attribute and then use the `[AllowAnonymous]` on the methods you want to have access.

Answer (score 1):

The start page just your default Controller that you provide in RouteConfig. So if you are using the default values you need to allow acces to `HomeController` and the `Index()` method. When working with MVC and authorization I find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) very valuable.